# How to measure robustness and stress?

Tags: stress-testing, software-quality, robustness

I'm working on an investigation on robustness and stress metrics, but I can't really find useful information. I did see that MTBF is an option for robustness on this question: [How to measure robustness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354379/how-to-measure-robustness). But I was wondering if there are any other metrics that can be used for measuring robustness and which metrics can we used for measuring stress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good Question. Software is different to electronics or mechanics because software incidents are not made by random faults (electronics) or wearing (mechanics), they are made by developers and ops engineers. This means you can't use MTBF to measure software robustness.

Two ideas to measure robustness:

1. calculate the availability of the software system - robustness have a direct impact to the software availability
2. calculate the robustness test coverage, analyze your historic incidents an try to replay them (daily) e.g. with your chaos monkey

[Blog article in German](https://programming-2.blogspot.de/2017/11/warum-brauchen-wir-robustness-test.html)